# How to create a geometry_msgs::Point?

Tags: c++, ros

I'm using ROS melodic.

This is not a robot problem, it is a C++ problem.

I'm trying this C++ code:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "geometry_msgs/Point.h"
#include "geometry_msgs/Twist.h"
#include "geometry_msgs/Quaternion.h"
#include "tf/transform_datatypes.h"
#include "tf/LinearMath/Matrix3x3.h"
#include "nav_msgs/Odometry.h"

#include <sstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <queue>

// ... More code

geometry_msgs::Point p;
```

But I get the following error message:

```
no instance of constructor "geometry_msgs::Point_<containerallocator>::Point_ [with ContainerAllocator=std::allocator<void>]" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (double, double)
```

This is [Point.h](http://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/geometry_msgs/html/Point_8h_source.html) header.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This error code tells you what is wrong here. `Point_` struct doesn't have a constructor that takes `double, double` as arguments

Comment: @Raffallo, thanks. But I don't understand that message because I'm not adding arguments in `geometry_msgs::Point p;`.

Comment: and this shouldn't be `geometry_msgs::Point_`? 
and maybe this error points to another line of the code?

Comment: @Raffallo, `geometry_msgs::Point p;` is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have added the `geometry_msgs` in your `package.xml` and `CMakeLists.txt`. If not then just add it.

In **package.xml** add:

```
<depend>geometry_msgs</depend>
```

In **CMakeLists.txt** add:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  geometry_msgs
)

catkin_package(
  CATKIN_DEPENDS geometry_msgs
)
```